# How do I refresh a TMS layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: refresh, openlayers, layer, tms

I have a TMS layer that looks something like this:

```
var v = 1;
my_tms = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS(
    "My TMS",
    "my_mapserver.php?v="+my_var+"&",
     { transparent: 'true', type:'png', getURL:get_my_url }
);
```

Where my_mapserver.php returns map tiles according to the value of v.

The app allows users to change v, and I simply want to refresh the my_tms layer, however, so far the only way I can get it to refresh is by destroying the map and recreating it.

I thought I could just do something like this:

```
v = 2;
my_tms = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS(
    "My TMS",
    "my_mapserver.php?v="+my_var+"&",
     { transparent: 'true', type:'png', getURL:get_my_url }
);
my_tms.redraw();
```

However, these tiles are not getting requested when I redraw().

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Oops... I meant to say my_var = 1 and my_var = 2 rather that v = 1 and v = 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TMS layers inherits from Grid layer you could try to call clearGrid() method to remove all existing tiles and then spiralTileLoad() to load new ones.

Comment: Thank you!  I found I did not need clearGrid(), but rather just my_tms.url = "my_mapserver.php?v="+my_var+"&"; my_tms.spiralTileLoad(); my_tms.redraw();

Answer (score 0):

`layer.redraw();`, `OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh` and `clearGrid()` didn't help me in reloading tiles of `OpenLayers.Layer.TMS` layer in OpenLayers 2.13.1, but helped:

```
layer.mergeNewParams({});
```